# Iterar sobre las fechas del índice de filas de un DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter

Disponemos del siguiente DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

# Diccionario dicc_retornos
dicc_retornos = {'Close': {Timestamp('2010-12-30 00:00:00'): 9859.099609375, Timestamp('2011-01-03 00:00:00'): 9888.2998046875, Timestamp('2011-01-04 00:00:00'): 9888.400390625, Timestamp('2011-01-05 00:00:00'): 9801.400390625, Timestamp('2011-01-06 00:00:00'): 9702.7001953125, Timestamp('2011-01-07 00:00:00'): 9560.7001953125, Timestamp('2011-01-10 00:00:00'): 9437.7998046875, Timestamp('2011-01-11 00:00:00'): 9582.099609375, Timestamp('2011-01-12 00:00:00'): 10101.2001953125, Timestamp('2011-01-13 00:00:00'): 10370.7998046875, Timestamp('2011-01-14 00:00:00'): 10385.099609375, Timestamp('2011-01-17 00:00:00'): 10280.0, Timestamp('2011-01-18 00:00:00'): 10583.400390625, Timestamp('2011-01-19 00:00:00'): 10556.5, Timestamp('2011-01-20 00:00:00'): 10636.900390625, Timestamp('2011-01-21 00:00:00'): 10829.099609375, Timestamp('2011-01-24 00:00:00'): 10815.400390625, Timestamp('2011-01-25 00:00:00'): 10664.400390625, Timestamp('2011-01-26 00:00:00'): 10670.7001953125, Timestamp('2011-01-27 00:00:00'): 10828.7001953125}, 'EMA_100': {Timestamp('2010-12-30 00:00:00'): 9859.099609375, Timestamp('2011-01-03 00:00:00'): 9859.677831064357, Timestamp('2011-01-04 00:00:00'): 9860.246594620012, Timestamp('2011-01-05 00:00:00'): 9859.081323253773, Timestamp('2011-01-06 00:00:00'): 9855.984667254936, Timestamp('2011-01-07 00:00:00'): 9850.137449988748, Timestamp('2011-01-10 00:00:00'): 9841.972348101595, Timestamp('2011-01-11 00:00:00'): 9836.826353275326, Timestamp('2011-01-12 00:00:00'): 9842.061478860222, Timestamp('2011-01-13 00:00:00'): 9852.531544718187, Timestamp('2011-01-14 00:00:00'): 9863.07744698862, Timestamp('2011-01-17 00:00:00'): 9871.33333912746, Timestamp('2011-01-18 00:00:00'): 9885.433676780875, Timestamp('2011-01-19 00:00:00'): 9898.722118824819, Timestamp('2011-01-20 00:00:00'): 9913.339510345613, Timestamp('2011-01-21 00:00:00'): 9931.47337369273, Timestamp('2011-01-24 00:00:00'): 9948.976878978518, Timestamp('2011-01-25 00:00:00'): 9963.143681189338, Timestamp('2011-01-26 00:00:00'): 9977.154701270985, Timestamp('2011-01-27 00:00:00'): 9994.016988281708}, 'EMA_200': {Timestamp('2010-12-30 00:00:00'): 9859.099609375, Timestamp('2011-01-03 00:00:00'): 9859.39015858209, Timestamp('2011-01-04 00:00:00'): 9859.678817607391, Timestamp('2011-01-05 00:00:00'): 9859.098932761797, Timestamp('2011-01-06 00:00:00'): 9857.542726419018, Timestamp('2011-01-07 00:00:00'): 9854.589069393083, Timestamp('2011-01-10 00:00:00'): 9850.441912530341, Timestamp('2011-01-11 00:00:00'): 9847.77183986213, Timestamp('2011-01-12 00:00:00'): 9850.29351504074, Timestamp('2011-01-13 00:00:00'): 9855.472682101901, Timestamp('2011-01-14 00:00:00'): 9860.742601776261, Timestamp('2011-01-17 00:00:00'): 9864.914317181474, Timestamp('2011-01-18 00:00:00'): 9872.063432340117, Timestamp('2011-01-19 00:00:00'): 9878.873746446185, Timestamp('2011-01-20 00:00:00'): 9886.416300119607, Timestamp('2011-01-21 00:00:00'): 9895.796233545034, Timestamp('2011-01-24 00:00:00'): 9904.946523665234, Timestamp('2011-01-25 00:00:00'): 9912.503278560356, Timestamp('2011-01-26 00:00:00'): 9920.047526488239, Timestamp('2011-01-27 00:00:00'): 9929.088846576044}, 'Position': {Timestamp('2010-12-30 00:00:00'): 0.0, Timestamp('2011-01-03 00:00:00'): 1.0, Timestamp('2011-01-04 00:00:00'): 1.0, Timestamp('2011-01-05 00:00:00'): 0.0, Timestamp('2011-01-06 00:00:00'): 0.0, Timestamp('2011-01-07 00:00:00'): 0.0, Timestamp('2011-01-10 00:00:00'): 0.0, Timestamp('2011-01-11 00:00:00'): 0.0, Timestamp('2011-01-12 00:00:00'): 0.0, Timestamp('2011-01-13 00:00:00'): 0.0, Timestamp('2011-01-14 00:00:00'): 1.0, Timestamp('2011-01-17 00:00:00'): 1.0, Timestamp('2011-01-18 00:00:00'): 1.0, Timestamp('2011-01-19 00:00:00'): 1.0, Timestamp('2011-01-20 00:00:00'): 1.0, Timestamp('2011-01-21 00:00:00'): 1.0, Timestamp('2011-01-24 00:00:00'): 1.0, Timestamp('2011-01-25 00:00:00'): 1.0, Timestamp('2011-01-26 00:00:00'): 1.0, Timestamp('2011-01-27 00:00:00'): 1.0}}

# Convertir el diccionario en un DataFrame
datos_df = pd.DataFrame(dicc_retornos)
```

El códgo siguiente.

```
stop_loss_pct = 0.05  # Porcentaje de stop loss (2% en este ejemplo)
take_profit_pct = 0.05  # Porcentaje de take profit (5% en este ejemplo)

# Calcular stop loss y take profit
datos_df['Stop_loss'] = datos_df['Close'] * (1 - stop_loss_pct)
datos_df['Take_profit'] = datos_df['Close'] * (1 + take_profit_pct)

# Aplicar trailing stop y take profit
for date_index in datos_df.index[1:]:
    # Comprueba si la posición es una señal de compra o venta
    if datos_df.loc[date_index, 'Position'] == 1:  # Señal de compra
        # Calcular stop loss para posiciones largas
        stop_loss_triggered_long = datos_df.loc[date_index, 'Close'] < datos_df.loc[date_index - pd.Timedelta(days=1), 'Stop_loss']
        if stop_loss_triggered_long:
            datos_df.loc[date_index:, 'Position'] = 0  # Vender si se alcanza el stop loss
        
        # Calcular take profit para posiciones largas
        take_profit_triggered_long = datos_df.loc[date_index, 'Close'] > datos_df.loc[date_index - pd.Timedelta(days=1), 'Take_profit']
        if take_profit_triggered_long:
            datos_df.loc[date_index:, 'Position'] = 0  # Vender si se alcanza el take profit
            
    elif datos_df.loc[date_index, 'Position'] == -1:  # Señal de venta
        # Calcular stop loss para posiciones cortas
        stop_loss_triggered_short = datos_df.loc[date_index, 'Close'] > datos_df.loc[date_index - pd.Timedelta(days=1), 'Stop_loss']
        if stop_loss_triggered_short:
            datos_df.loc[date_index:, 'Position'] = 0  # Comprar si se alcanza el stop loss
        
        # Calcular take profit para posiciones cortas
        take_profit_triggered_short = datos_df.loc[date_index, 'Close'] < datos_df.loc[date_index - pd.Timedelta(days=1), 'Take_profit']
        if take_profit_triggered_short:
            datos_df.loc[date_index:, 'Position'] = 0  # Comprar si se alcanza el take profit
```

Me devuelve el error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~/Descargas/yes/envs/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/_libs/index.pyx:581, in pandas._libs.index.DatetimeEngine.get_loc()

File pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi:2606, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

File pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi:2630, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 1293926400000000000

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~/Descargas/yes/envs/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py:3653, in Index.get_loc(self, key)
   3652 try:
-> 3653     return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3654 except KeyError as err:

File ~/Descargas/yes/envs/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/_libs/index.pyx:549, in pandas._libs.index.DatetimeEngine.get_loc()

File ~/Descargas/yes/envs/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/_libs/index.pyx:583, in pandas._libs.index.DatetimeEngine.get_loc()

KeyError: Timestamp('2011-01-02 00:00:00')

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~/Descargas/yes/envs/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/datetimes.py:584, in DatetimeIndex.get_loc(self, key)
    583 try:
--> 584     return Index.get_loc(self, key)
    585 except KeyError as err:

File ~/Descargas/yes/envs/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py:3655, in Index.get_loc(self, key)
   3654 except KeyError as err:
-> 3655     raise KeyError(key) from err
   3656 except TypeError:
   3657     # If we have a listlike key, _check_indexing_error will raise
   3658     #  InvalidIndexError. Otherwise we fall through and re-raise
   3659     #  the TypeError.

KeyError: Timestamp('2011-01-02 00:00:00')

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[20], line 16
     12 for date_index in datos_df.index[1:]:
     13     # Comprueba si la posición es una señal de compra o venta
     14     if datos_df.loc[date_index, 'Position'] == 1:  # Señal de compra
     15         # Calcular stop loss para posiciones largas
---> 16         stop_loss_triggered_long = datos_df.loc[date_index, 'Close'] < datos_df.loc[date_index - pd.Timedelta(days=1), 'Stop_loss']
     17         if stop_loss_triggered_long:
     18             datos_df.loc[date_index:, 'Position'] = 0  # Vender si se alcanza el stop loss

File ~/Descargas/yes/envs/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:1096, in _LocationIndexer.__getitem__(self, key)
   1094     key = tuple(com.apply_if_callable(x, self.obj) for x in key)
   1095     if self._is_scalar_access(key):
-> 1096         return self.obj._get_value(*key, takeable=self._takeable)
   1097     return self._getitem_tuple(key)
   1098 else:
   1099     # we by definition only have the 0th axis

File ~/Descargas/yes/envs/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:3877, in DataFrame._get_value(self, index, col, takeable)
   3871 engine = self.index._engine
   3873 if not isinstance(self.index, MultiIndex):
   3874     # CategoricalIndex: Trying to use the engine fastpath may give incorrect
   3875     #  results if our categories are integers that dont match our codes
   3876     # IntervalIndex: IntervalTree has no get_loc
-> 3877     row = self.index.get_loc(index)
   3878     return series._values[row]
   3880 # For MultiIndex going through engine effectively restricts us to
   3881 #  same-length tuples; see test_get_set_value_no_partial_indexing

File ~/Descargas/yes/envs/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/datetimes.py:586, in DatetimeIndex.get_loc(self, key)
    584     return Index.get_loc(self, key)
    585 except KeyError as err:
--> 586     raise KeyError(orig_key) from err

KeyError: Timestamp('2011-01-02 00:00:00')
```

La fecha '2011-01-02 00:00:00', no está en los registros de mi diccionario porque, el índice de las filas son fechas en las que habido cotizaciones en la bolsa. ¿Cómo puedo solucionar este problema?. Aradeceré ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Dice que:

> La fecha '2011-01-02 00:00:00', no está en los registros de mi diccionario...

Pero en el código tienes esto varias veces:

```python
... datos_df.loc[date_index - pd.Timedelta(days=1), '<index>']
```

¿Qué crees que sucede cuando la fecha es `pd.Timestamp('2011-01-03')` y le restas 1 día? Exacto, comparas contra **2011-01-02** y ese índice NO EXISTE en el dataframe. Lo mismo pasaría con 2011-01-10, 2011-01-17, etc. Entonces no puedes usar como referencia restar días.

Sé muy poco sobre dataframes, y, arriesgándome a recibir el *voto de castigo*, podría sugerir que almacenes en una variable `last_date_index` la fila anterior para que compares contra la fila actual.

```python
stop_loss_pct = 0.05  # Porcentaje de stop loss (2% en este ejemplo)
take_profit_pct = 0.05  # Porcentaje de take profit (5% en este ejemplo)

# Calcular stop loss y take profit
datos_df['Stop_loss'] = datos_df['Close'] * (1 - stop_loss_pct)
datos_df['Take_profit'] = datos_df['Close'] * (1 + take_profit_pct)

# Aplicar trailing stop y take profit
last_date_index = datos_df.index[0] # <-- ** Agregar esto
for date_index in datos_df.index[1:]:
    # Comprueba si la posición es una señal de compra o venta
    if datos_df.loc[date_index, 'Position'] == 1:  # Señal de compra
        # Calcular stop loss para posiciones largas
        stop_loss_triggered_long = datos_df.loc[date_index, 'Close'] < datos_df.loc[last_date_index, 'Stop_loss']
        if stop_loss_triggered_long:
            datos_df.loc[date_index:, 'Position'] = 0  # Vender si se alcanza el stop loss
        
        # Calcular take profit para posiciones largas
        take_profit_triggered_long = datos_df.loc[date_index, 'Close'] > datos_df.loc[last_date_index, 'Take_profit']
        if take_profit_triggered_long:
            datos_df.loc[date_index:, 'Position'] = 0  # Vender si se alcanza el take profit
            
    elif datos_df.loc[date_index, 'Position'] == -1:  # Señal de venta
        # Calcular stop loss para posiciones cortas
        stop_loss_triggered_short = datos_df.loc[date_index, 'Close'] > datos_df.loc[last_date_index, 'Stop_loss']
        if stop_loss_triggered_short:
            datos_df.loc[date_index:, 'Position'] = 0  # Comprar si se alcanza el stop loss
        
        # Calcular take profit para posiciones cortas
        take_profit_triggered_short = datos_df.loc[date_index, 'Close'] < datos_df.loc[last_date_index, 'Take_profit']
        if take_profit_triggered_short:
            datos_df.loc[date_index:, 'Position'] = 0  # Comprar si se alcanza el take profit 
    last_date_index = date_index # <-- ** Agregar esto
```